# Php pdo request arrays: How to single out the columns identified by numbers

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm using `pdo`/`php 5.3.10` to extract data from a `mysql` table. 
Say I want the id of an email address, I execute the following:

```
    $req = $linkpdo->prepare('SELECT idEmail FROM AERA.email WHERE adresse= ?');
    $req -> execute(array($_POST['email1']));
    $idEmailTab = $req->fetchAll();
```

Fair enough. But the array it gives me looks something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [idEmail] => 8 [0] => 8 ) )
```

I have the same value twice, which is a pain because I want to use a `foreach` on the results.
Here is the code I am testing it with:

```
foreach($idEmailTab[0] as $id){
        $req = $linkpdo->prepare('INSERT INTO AERA.pers_email(idPers, idEmail)
                                    VALUES (:idPers, :idEmail)');
        $req -> execute(array('idPers'=>$idPers, 'idEmail'=>$id));
        echo "gone in";
    }
```

How can I "extract" one of the two results? (either the name, or the number, but prefereably the number)

**UPDATE**
I have currently fudged it so:

```
$i = 0;
    foreach($idEmailTab[0] as $id){
        if($i%2==0){
            $req = $linkpdo->prepare('INSERT INTO AERA.pers_email(idPers, idEmail)
                                VALUES (:idPers, :idEmail)');
            $req -> execute(array('idPers'=>$idPers, 'idEmail'=>$id));
            echo "gone in";
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

If anyone has a more practical suggestion, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$idEmailTab = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will fetch the result as an associative array only.

```
$idEmailTab = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

This will fetch the result as an array indexed by column number

Answer (score -2):

Well, this question is just a entanglement of confusions.

- First, iterating over the resulting array is not a pain nor a slightest problem. Just iterate over the *initial array*.
- Second, I doubt you need to iterate at all. Just use the proper way to get your single result from the statement.
- Third. In case you really need a flattened array consists of multiple elements from fetchAll(), you have to use PDO::FECTCH_COLUMN mode.

But again, for this case you need not a single loop here

```
$req = $linkpdo->prepare('SELECT idEmail FROM AERA.email WHERE adresse= ?');
$req -> execute(array($_POST['email1']));
$idEmail = $req->fetchColumn();

$req = $linkpdo->prepare('INSERT INTO AERA.pers_email(idPers, idEmail)
                                VALUES (:idPers, :idEmail)');
$req -> execute(array('idPers'=>$idPers, 'idEmail'=>$idEmail));
echo "gone in";
```